# dropdownlist issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a dropdownlist generated from db. Here is the result from page source.

```
<select id="testList" name="testList">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="0">A</option>
<option value="1">B</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone know why the empty is still zero? How come I dont get something like "" for the first one since it's empty?

```
<div class="editor-field">
<%= Html.DropDownList("list") %>
</div>

ViewData["list"] = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Value");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I suppose that you have used a value type such as Int32 for the `Id` property. Try using a nullable integer instead: `int?`

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov -- thanks, by changing int to int? solved it.